# How to connect Raspberry Pi to the serial interface (TTL) of a Cubieboard?

Tags: hardware, serial

Can I use a Raspberry Pi as an adapter for connecting to [Cubieboard TTL](http://linux-sunxi.org/Cubieboard/TTL)?
I don't have USB-Serial adapter but need to read it.

Comment: if you don't have USB-Serial adapter, why don't you get one? or make one? these are available practically everywhere nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi has an on-board RS232 port, see [this article on elinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#Connection_to_a_microcontroller_or_other_peripheral).

You will have to configure your Pi so Linux itself won't block the port <strike>and since the Raspberry Pi operates at **3.3V** and the Cubieboard seems to use TTL levels, i.e. **5V**, **you will still need a level converter**</strike>.

**Edit:** Apparently, the Cubieboard uses 3.3V levels for its RS232 interface, so you should be able to connect the GND and data lines directly to the Pi (don't connect VCC, though!).